# Bubble Highmap using Lat Long

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working on drawing a bubble map using highcharts and i have reached to a certain point where I am successfully plotting the bubble based on the state code (in/RJ) and value (1000).

http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/h2f4ugz4/

```
$(function () {


var mapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/in/in-all']);

var data = [{
    "z": 10038,
        "code": "RJ"
}, {
    "z": 100,
        "code": "PB"
}];

$('#container').highcharts('Map', {
    chart: {
        borderWidth: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'World population 2010 by country'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Demo of Highcharts map with bubbles'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Countries',
        mapData: mapData,
        color: '#E0E0E0',
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }, {
        type: 'mapbubble',
        mapData: mapData,
        name: 'Population 2010',
        data: data,
        joinBy: ['postal-code', 'code'],
        minSize: 4,
        maxSize: '12%',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
        }
    }]
});

});
```

But instead of using the state code I want to make the bubble using latitude and longitude, and i am not getting any hint how to do it.

For example the lat long of (RJ) Rajasthan (a state of india) using it's lat long 26.5727° N, 73.8390° E.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of small steps you need to take. First of all, include Proj4s, which does the coordinate system conversion. This boils down to:

```
<script src="http://.../proj4.js"></script>
```

Secondly, you should swap your `mapData` to look like this:

```
var mapData = Highcharts.maps['countries/in/in-all'];
```

The reason for this is that wrapping it in `Highcharts.geojson` means Highmaps doesn't recognize it as a map from their own collection, and won't allow for easy lat/lng conversion.

The last thing is to place the bubbles using latitude and longitude, like this:

```
var data =  [{
    "z": 10038,
    "lat": 26.5727,
    "lon": 73.8390
    // "code": "RJ"
}, {
    "z": 100,
    "code": "PB"
}];
```

See [this updated JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/h2f4ugz4/1/), which uses lat/lng for Rajasthan (RJ).

Comment: Thanks, But their is no bubble at the specified lat/lon.

Comment: The RJ bubble isn't showing for you? Browser? Looks fine for me in Chrome. Also, anything in console?

Comment: I am also using chrome here. I hope you are not getting confused with the bubble with code **PB**, their are two elements in the array.

Comment: This is what I'm seeing: http://i.imgur.com/XqutPgU.png The big one is RJ (with lat/lng), and the small one is PB. Correct? (as you can see the URL is that of the updated JSFiddle)

Comment: Also, try this one, which keeps the `code` uncommented: http://jsfiddle.net/h2f4ugz4/2/ -- it may be that you should keep it there to make the `joinBy` work.

Comment: Well that's highly unusual. How about the second JSFiddle linked in the comment above?

Comment: I tried firefox as well.. The error on console is Highcharts error #21: www.highcharts.com/errors/21

Comment: Ah okay. So somehow the `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.2.2/proj4.js` isn't being loaded. Possibly some cross domain type of problem? It could be that it works better if you have it locally and download that js-file.

Comment: I am not even able to access the file directly using the browser.

Comment: I'm not sure what I've done (or not done) to get access there, but in any case you can get their latest release here: https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/releases and then include that file locally.

Comment: The reason I'm using that particular URL for the proj4js is that it's the one included in [Highmaps official lat/lng demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/mappoint-latlon/).

Comment: Yes, true, probably that is why that particular demo was not showing any data at my end. Thanks man! I will try to do it locally.

Comment: Hey @Ondkloss, can i plot "RJ" on world map, It is a state.

Comment: What do you mean by plot in this case?

Comment: What i mean is can i show states on a world map in highcharts? All the examples highchart have is of countries on world map.

Comment: I'm not sure of the top of my head. Sounds like a new question. I haven't seen it done myself either.

Comment: I want to show a bubble on `RJ` on world map (using the state code not lat long).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73018/discussion-between-ondkloss-and-void).